# C#, there is a thread and it doesn't stops!

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

C#, i started a thread, and i did `IsBackground=true`, didn't work, anyway, after this i exit the program the thread is still working and the program not closing.

what should i do?

Comment: you should post your code here ;-)

Comment: You are going to proivde a whole lot more code and an idea n what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Start writing thread safe code.

Comment: @harper89 Smashing it over the head is not the way to go...

Comment: I think we would have to solve the Halting Problem to answer this question conclusively.

Comment: Okay, there is another problem, when i start the program without debugging then when i close the program after 30 seconds it gives me an error that the program has stopped working, what is this?

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx):

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread.
>   Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that
>   background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all
>   foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common
>   language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads
>   are stopped and do not complete.

I must be some other thread that prevents your process from terminating.

**Update:**

It looks like one of your threads has a kind of infinite loop (which contains code that spawns other background threads, probably). I would bet that this thread stops the process from terminating and this infinite loop causes the error you've mentioned.

It's impossible to tell without any source code.

Comment: All the thread are IsBackground = true, all of them, i just don't get it, why is the program start running even after i closed it.

Comment: Okay, there is another problem, when i start the program without debugging then when i close the program after 30 seconds it gives me an error that the program has stopped working, what is this?

Answer (score 0):

You should always be able to close it from Task Manager. Ctrl + Alt + Delete -> Task Manager OR right click on the task bar at the bottom of your screen and go to Task Manager.

As for fixing your thread issue you need to give more details so that we can help fix that issue.

Comment: Okay, there is another problem, when i start the program without debugging then when i close the program after 30 seconds it gives me an error that the program has stopped working, what is this?

Comment: To me it seems like it just shows that it had to force kill it, because your threads aren't being safely stopped.